# Process exits midway. Not completing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, process, nunit

I have been trying to run Nunit console app through my C# console application to run a set a unit test cases. But whats happening is some of the unit test cases start, go halfway and remains incomplete  and exits some how and starts the next unit test case. Below is the code  for running the the Nunit console application.

```
 var processArgs =String.Format(@" /process:Separate /run:{0}.{1}.{2} "D:\AcceptanceTest.dll"" /noshadow /xml:{3} /labels /out:{4}",
                                classNameString, type.Name, testMethod, xmlFeatureFile, txtFeatureOutputFile);

Process process = null;
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = null;
    processStartInfo =
        new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console.exe",
            processArgs)
        {
            WorkingDirectory = @"D:\TestOutput",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            ErrorDialog = false,
        };

    // *** Run test in nunit here ***
    process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    if (process != null)
            {
                var hasExited = process.WaitForExit(3600000);
                if (!hasExited)
                    Log.Debug("Wait for exit returned before process exited.");
            }
        }

catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error("Error related to nunit-console.exe:", ex);
}
finally
{
    if (process != null)
    {
        process.Close();
        process.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts what might be going wrong in here? There are no errors when I inspect the logs for the application.

Comment: Get rid of the `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` and see if there are any errors in the console window.

Comment: why the specflow tag? doesn't seem like your issue is specflow related